# Docker+Log4j best practice

Tags: java, maven, docker, log4j

I am building a small Java application that runs on the open-jdk docker through a `java -jar myJar.jar` entrypoint command.
I would like to add logging configuration using Log4j.
Here is what i know(?) i should do:

1.Keep log4j.xml in a seperate source folder like src/resource .
2.Keep log4j.xml outside the JAR file in the docker, to allow configuration during runtime .
3. Let the JVM know where the log4j.xml file is (probably using classpath).

There are multiple ways to achieve this - the log4j.xml location can be configured via an argument to `jar -jar` command, it can be added in a mvn plugin, it can be added as a command into the Dockerfile (probably?).

**Is there a best practice where all of these configuration should be included in pom.xml/Dockerfile/Docker entrypoint command ?**

Comment: When you decide to move to Docker you should not rely anymore on logs inside the container. For that reason make sure you add a CONSOLE appender to your log4j. This way you can pick your logs from outside the container (either docker logs or another container if you change the logging driver. In my opinion the location of the log4j.xml is not that important when you decide to move to docker.

Comment: I understand that, but i still need the configuration i mentioned + the log4j.xml to be able to change the debug level while the docker running, right? Or does the best practice for docker is just to keep it on INFO level?

Comment: Ideally nothing should change inside the container after it starts. You can build for dev and for prod and use different profiles at build time. That being said, you should be able to see all the logs you need without loging into the container.

Comment: So application running inside a docker should not support change in debug level? They should be built with a specific level depending on the environment and stay in that log level forever?

Comment: You build your image. When you start a container based on that image you can specify through an environment variable how your logging should be. That is one approach. Or you build different images per environment. Usually you only want debug in development and most surely that comes also with other settings specific to development. And you don't want those leaked into production. For this reason it is a good practice to build image for specific profiles (development, production, etc.).

Comment: So a docker in deployment should only show INFO level debug? What's the point of having a logging framework if we don't change the debug level ever?

Comment: do you change log levels in a running application? docker images can be rebuilt whenever needed. so yes log levels can be changed. and if you really love logging so much you should look into an ELK stack. put everything to debug and then filter it and index it from ElasticSearch.

Comment: I have a sprint boot application which uses log4j2 to write logs. When I deploy this application to a Docker container, I want the logs to be wriiten to a file at a specified location outside the container. How can I do this ? I tried providing the path of the log folder using an environment variable on startup but its of no use. No logs are being written. Please help

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, following Mihai comments and other resources, is that the docker image should be built to support a logging configuration that will be included when the container is lunched (using docker run arguments for example). This way the image is flexible enough to support different debug levels.
In contrast to how non dockerised log4j usually works (or my understanding of it) - changing the debug level now includes stopping the old running container and lunching a new one, using the same image with a different runtime configration.
For example, if the image name is dockerTestImage.
We would first do something like:
`docker run -DebugLevel=INFO dockerTestImage`.
Then, if we want more verbouse logging for any reason, we would stop the old container and run a new one using `docker run -DebugLevel=DEBUG dockerTestImage`.